# mySQL syntax error for "=0"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a query for results that match the decimal number = 0.00, and then another query where I want to find results that are > than 0.00.

I must do this with only one variable and one query sentence.

So I wrote:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE price $price
```

and the `$price` variable can then have two values, one is: `"= 0.00"`, and another `"> 0.00"`

But I get the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"= 0.00" LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Is there some other way around this, to have the result I wan't? any ideas?

(I must have one sentence, one variable...)

Comment: Please post your complete code, please NOTE the way you are doing it opens you up to SQL injection as you are allowing users to modify your SQL directly

Comment: Can you show what `$price` contains

Comment: @Deepu, he does in the fourth paragraph.

Comment: Show your code, you are abstracting your SQL which is where the error is, I suspect it is just a single quote issue `'`

Comment: How are you executing that? The error message implies it is being passed in as a quoted string.

Comment: I'm setting the variable from an internal code in my android app (its not an user editable..) and send it to a php script. Then the php script takes this variable and put's it into the SQL statement as seen above.

Comment: You need to replace the quotes in the variable with empty Strings.

Comment: @belosand, it looks like you're somehow escaping = 0.00 and placing double quotes around the whole thing. ie - "= 0.00" is what $price actually equates to.

Comment: Yes the the android code sends a string ("= 0.00" or "> 0.00") parameter to php script, there this parameter becomes the $price variable, like $price = $_GET['price']; and then I insert that into the above SQL statement.

Comment: please post the actual code where you assemble the query with variable.

Comment: Also if I do a direct query in the phpMyAdmin like: `SELECT *FROM table WHERE price"> 0.00"` i get the same error... so i dont have double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your column data type, price can either be seen in the database as a string, or an actual float/double. Check your column data type so you can create the correct comparison type, aka price = 0.00, or price = '0.00'. There are numerous advantages depending what data type your column is stored as, arithmetic can be performed inline, but if your data type is varchar/some sort of string equivalent, you won't be able to utilize the built-in methods inside of whatever SQL engine you are using.